# nonatomic measure on unit sphere and diameter of set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

let $\mu$ be a nonatomic probability measure on unit sphere $S^d$.

is it possible to construct a partition $(A_i)_{i=1...}$of  $S^d$ such that $\forall i  $  diam$(A_i)<\mu(A_i)$

where diam$(A_i)$ is the diameter of $A_i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are measuring the diameter using the Euclidean metric (although the answer for the arclength metric is very similar, just with a different critical value).

I claim that the answer is no, at least for finite partitions. More generally, I will prove that such a finite partition exists on a sphere of radius $r$ if and only if $r< \frac{1}{2}$.

Indeed, if $S_r$ is a sphere of radius $r<1/2$, then diam$ (S_r)=2r<1=\mu(S_r)$ and therefore we can take our partition to be the singleton $\{S_r\}$.

Conversely, suppose that $S_r$ is a sphere of radius $r\ge 1/2$. Then for any finite partition $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^N$ of $S_r$, I claim that $$\sum_k \text{diam}(A_k) \geq \text{diam}(S_r)=2r \geq 1 = \mu(S_r) = \sum_k \mu(A_k)$$
and therefore there exists some $k$ such that diam$(A_k) \geq \mu(A_k)$. The only nontrivial part of this expression is the first inequality: $\sum_k \text{diam}(A_k) \geq \text{diam}(S_r)$, so we will prove this. First, we note that if $A,B$ are any sets such that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, then $$\text{diam}(A)+\text{diam}(B) \geq \text{diam}(A \cup B)$$ Indeed, for any $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, we let $z \in A \cap B$ and we have that $$|x-y| \leq |x-z|+|z-y| \leq \text{diam}(A)+\text{diam}(B)$$ Now given our partition $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^N$, we assume wlog that $\overline A_k \cap \overline A_{k+1} \neq \emptyset$ for all $k< N$ (this must hold after some reordering of the $A_i$, by the connectedness of $S_r$). Then by repeatedly applying the above observation (and using the fact that any set and its closure have the same diameter) we find \begin{align*}\text{diam}(S_r) &\le \text{diam}(A_1)+ \text{diam} \bigg( \bigcup_{k=2}^N A_k \bigg) \\ & \leq \text{diam}(A_1)+\text{diam}(A_2)+\text{diam}\bigg( \bigcup_{k=3}^N A_k \bigg) \\ &\leq \text{diam}(A_1)+\text{diam}(A_2)+\text{diam}(A_3)+ \text{diam}\bigg( \bigcup_{k=4}^N A_k \bigg) \\ &\dots \dots \dots \\ &\leq \sum_{k=1}^N \text{diam}(A_k)
\end{align*}
which is the desired result.